# How to link a jQuery file into SharePoint html page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, jquery, custom-masterpage

I need to link a jQuery file into SharePoint HTML file(not master page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Upload Jquery file to `Style Library` at SharePoint at the root site
- Open HTML file Via SharePoint designer
- Add it as `<script src="../Style Library/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`
- Or write src= to show Pick dialog to can select it's place.

[image]

Also, you can use the script from Google Hosted Libraries without upload, but this will require internet connection

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```